# problema con codigo para reinstalar la store de windows 10

Tags: windows, windows10, powershell, store

no se si sea el codigo o mi pc he probado con los siguientes codigos

```
d C:\Users/usuario\desktop\ .\reinstall-preinstalledApps.ps1 Microsoft.WindowsStore

cd C:\Users\usuario\Desktop>.\reinstall-preinstalledApp.ps1
```

por si lo que sea  el problema es despues de haber formateado el windows de fabrica guardando los archivos personales

Answer (score 0):

Sigue ésta secuencia o creas un scrip con los comandos

abres el powershell como administrador

te situas en tu escritorio com:

```
CD C:\Users\tu carpeta de usuario\Desktop
```

tecleas lo siguiente:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Le das a 'y' (yes) para elegir la opción

Continúas con:

```
.\reinstall-preinstalledApps.ps1
```

Ahora lo siguiente

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned
```

vuelves a poner 'y' (yes) como opción

EDITADA:

Encontré ésta solución por internet a tu problema, espero te sirva:

- Abre Powershell ejecutándolo como administrador (esto es primordial)
- Copia y ejecuta en Powershell...

  Get-AppxPackage -allusers | Select Name, PackageFullName

(de esa forma te saldrán todas las aplicaciones con sus respectivos nombres)

- Busca la aplicación que quieras volver a reinstalar y COPIA el codigo que hay a su derecha

(si son varias aplicaciones a instalar, te recomendaría abrir un Bloc de notas por ejemplo y pegar allí el codigo de cada app para tener el listado)

- Una vez tengas los codigos de las apps que quieras volver a reinstalar en Powershell escribe lo siguiente...

  Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PackageCodeName\appxmanifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode

La parte del código que pone PackageCodeName la tienes que sustituir por el código de la aplicación que copiaste antes en el paso anterior.

Al darle a Intro, la app por defecto aparecerá en el menú Inicio al instante.

Si no lo hace, reinicia el PC.

Comment: @elel.trasgu me aparece este error .\reinstall-preinstalledApps.ps1 : El término '.\reinstall-preinstalledApps.ps1' no se reconoce como nombre de un
cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si
incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.

Comment: Te acabo de responder editando mi respuesta

Comment: dd-AppxPackage : No se encuentra la ruta de acceso 'C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\1527c705-839a-4832-9118-54d4Bd6a0c89_10.0.18362.449_neutral_neutral_cw5n\appxmanifest.xml' porque no
existe.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\1527c705-839a ...
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...ppxmanifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], ItemNotFou
   ndException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand Me aparece esto ahora quiero la store

Comment: Pues siento decirte que me he quedado sin más recursos